# Static linking libgcc on Windows DLL

Tags: c++, windows, dll, exception

I am writing a Windows DLL in C++. This library has only C interface and uses only standard Windows libraries which also have C interface. Therefore it seems me safe to statically link all C++ libraries into the library because I am not dependent on C++ ABI version when using C interfaces only.

Unfortunately when I compile my library with `-static-stdc++ -static-libgcc`, my library stops handling exceptions and when some exception is thrown, the DLL calls its statically linked `_Unwind_RaiseException` function which aborts the whole application.

I thought it could be a corrupted `libgtcc.a` so I tried to update my compiler. But the result is the same with both MinGW 4.8 and MinGW 6.3.

Please is anybody able to explain me what is really happening here?

Klasyc

Comment: Use TDM-GCC. See a brief explanation [here](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/quirks)

Comment: Or MinGW, which supports SEH.

Comment: @RustyX the OP has tried MinGW which as you say supports SEH but not if the libraries are statically linked and the exception is thrown across a DLL boundary.  This is one of the issues address by TDM-GCC.  MinGW is fine if the runtime libraries are dynamically linked (ie there is just one version of them in the process).

Comment: @RustyX: Why do I need compiler with SEH support? I thought SEH allows me to catch Windows exceptions like access violation etc, but I have problem even with basic C++ exceptions.

Comment: @Dan: I normally use C++/Qt which is normally shipped with QtCreator and MinGW. I am quite satisfied with this combination. Therefore I use it also for my DLL.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks RastyX for that simple example in his answer. After some research I found out that the application crashes when I compile DLL part with `-static-libgcc` and application part without this switch (both parts compiled with the same g++).

Also thanks to Ripi2 for TDM-GCC suggestion. I tried both SJLJ and DWARF-2 exception handling and both work.

To conclude it, it seems MinGW's libgcc does not like when it is instantiated more than once per process. In my case I use one its copy in DLL (linked statically) and one its copy in the application and this probably breaks the exception handling.

On the other hand TDM-GCC focuses on static linking of the basic libraries as its web page says and therefore produces binaries that depend only on Windows libraries even without `-static-stdc++ -static-libgcc` command line switches (this is what I want). Also the exception handling works here, so changing of the toolchain is the right way for me.

Comment: Wow thank you, you saved me, seems an xxx.a file (library) with .cpp files must be compiled with -static-xxx params same as exe that uses it or your exe will silently just die at startup.   I guess this happens because the library files call the static initializer and then the .exe calls the shared initializer which blows up?  Or vice versa? :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you handling all exceptions inside the DLL? If any exception "leaks" outside a function with a C calling convention, it will crash the application.

I am having no problems with C++ exceptions under **MinGW x86_64-5.3.0-win32-seh-rt_v4-rev0** and **mingw32 4.8.1 dwarf2** with a static libstdc++/libgcc.

DLL source (`dll.cpp`):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall test() {
    try {
        new int[-1];
        return 123;
    } catch (const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cerr << "Exception:" << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return 456;
    }
}
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD     fdwReason, LPVOID    lpvReserved)
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

Application source (`app.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
__declspec(dllimport) int __stdcall test();

int main() {
  printf("result: %d\n", test());
  return 0;
}
```

Compile it:

`g++ -O2 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -shared -Wl,--out-implib=dtest.lib -s -o dtest.dll dll.cpp`

`g++ -O2 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -L. -s -o app app.c -ldtest`

Output:

```
Exception:std::bad_alloc
result: 456
```

---

To answer your comment "*Why do I need compiler with SEH support? I thought SEH allows me to catch Windows exceptions*" - on Windows, SEH is the de-facto standard for *all exceptions*, including C++ exceptions (when compiled with Visual C++). MinGW has different implementations for C++ exceptions (SEH, SJLJ and DWARF), however SEH is the only mechanism with zero overhead, so if it's available you really should prefer it over SJLJ and DWARF.