# Cross-compiling a Windows DLL on Linux using Mingw

Tags: c++, linux, windows, mingw, cross-compiling

I am trying to deliver a Windows DLL (as well as a .so) from a Linux box using Mingw.

I am following [this example](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampledll), which consists of three files, the DLL source `example_dll.cpp`, header `example_dll.h`, and a client application `example_exe.cpp`. These I have located in a folder shared by my Linux host and Windows 7 VM. Both boxes have Mingw installed.

The build commands for the DLL are

1. `g++ -c -DBUILDING_EXAMPLE_DLL example_dll.cpp`
2. `g++ -shared -o example_dll.dll example_dll.o -Wl,--out-implib,libexample_dll.a`

and for the client app

3. `g++ -c example_exe.cpp`
4. `g++ -o example_exe.exe example_exe.o -L. -lexample_dll`

All compiles and runs perfectly on a Windows 7 VM with Mingw installed.

All compiles perfectly under Ubuntu 16.04 with Mingw installed, replacing `g++` with `i686-w64-mingw32-g++`.

But in this case, when the executable is run from the Windows VM, "The program can't start because libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll is missing.

- What mistake am I making?

I can force the "missing" DLLs into the executable, by replacing 4. with `i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -o example_exe.exe example_exe.o -L. -lexample_dll -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` on Linux, and that works perfectly on the Windows VM.

But I need to deliver a DLL, not an executable.

---

- I have noticed that the DLL libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll exists on the Linux box but not the Windows box.
- I have also noticed that the Linux box has Mingw 5.3.1 while the Windows box has Mingw 6.3.0

Comment: What happens if you tack `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` onto the end of command line #2?  Or is that not supported?  I believe the linker is still invoked when building a DLL.

Comment: @PaulSanders I tried that before, but no luck,

Comment: The command is accepted but when I run the exe the error still occurs.

Comment: Seems it _should_ work, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159583/static-linking-libgcc-on-windows-dll.  You would need to do it for the executable also, of course.

Comment: My problem is I can *only* deliver a DLL. The client will use my DLL as an API to make their own exe using compilers beyond my control. I will try 2. as you suggest on the linux box, and then 4. as you suggest on the Windows. Will update.

Comment: Yes that works. Your 2. on Linux. Deliver DLL. Your 4. on Windows. All is good. Are we hacking? Or is this how it must be done? Of course I am using Mingw on my Windows box simulating the client. If my client has Mingw installed but is using Visual Studio, will my DLL still be usable. If this is how it is meant to work, please feel free to post an answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Usable in what context?  To link with an executable built by Visual Studio?  Unlikely, I would have thought.  And another approach to your whole problem might be to supply `libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll` to your client, maybe that's a better solution.  I don't know enough about Mingw to say but you should at least investigate.